# TFS Command Line not executing when output redirected

Tags: command-line, tfs

Why is the 'Resolve Conflict' window not showing when i redirect the output to a text file as shown below

```
d:\tfstest\tf resolve  >myfile.txt
```

It shows when i choose not to redirect the output as follows:

```
d:\tfstest\tf resolve
```

Why is this happening????

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Are you trying to get the list of files which have a conflict?

Answer (score 0):

When you use a redirect it doesn't show UI because using redirects is something you normally do in a script which chains things together. So instead the expectation is that you call `tf resolve` for each conflict and pass the advanced parameters to tell it how to handle these conflicts (in combination with /noprompt):

> Microsoft (R) TF - Team Foundation Version Control Tool, Version
>   11.0.60315.1 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> Resolves conflicts between changed items in your workspace and the
>   latest or destination versions of items on the server.
>
> tf resolve [itemspec]
>   [/auto:(AutoMerge|AutoMergeForced|TakeTheirs|KeepYours|
>              OverwriteLocal|DeleteConflict|KeepYoursRenameTheirs)]
>              [/preview] [/recursive] [/newname:path] [/noprompt]
>              [(/overridetype:overridetype | /converttotype:converttype)]
>              [/properties:(@valuefile|name1=value1[;name2=value2;name3=@valuefile;
>   ...]
>              [/login:username,[password]]

Comment: Thnx Jesse ,  but i wondering if it is natural behaviour of Tfs to suppress UI Prompt  , if  there is a redirection of output.

Comment: It is for the commandline. When you redirect input/output the commandline tool assumes you don't want to combine that with UI.

Comment: ok..so is it possible to redirect ouput to a textfile and without compromising UI